Outlook shared mailbox auto reply to every mail
I have a problem that the "normal" autoreply only answers once to a specific e-mail but I need to answer to every mail I receive.
So, if a person sends 5 e-mails, I want to send 5 autoreply e-mails.
I tried to log in on OWA and set an autoreply and wrote a Powershell-script to enable autoreply.
but these solutions only answer once.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

On the low level (Extended MAPI - C++ or Delphi only), OOF rule has the ST_KEEP_OOF_HIST flag set, which forces it to keep history for each recipient and reply only once. The flag is not exposed through any other API supported by Outlook/Exchange.
If using Redemption (I am its author, any language) is an option, it exposes RDORule.KeepOOFHistory property, which you can set to false for the OOF rule. RDORule objects are accessible from the RDOExchangeMailboxStore.Rules collection.
